# No plugin found for prefix 'deploy' in the current project and in the plugin groups

Tags: maven

I am trying to upload an artifact which is not built by Maven. I am running the following cmd:

```
@mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=C:\Users\XX\myArtifact.zip -Dname=myArtifact -DartifactId=ServerBinaries -DgroupId=org.myArtifact -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=zip -DrepositoryId=xxxx -Durl=http://xxxx/repository/thirdparty -DgeneratePom=true
```

And ending up getting an error:

> No plugin found for prefix 'deploy' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\XXXX.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]

Which is preceded by a bunch of warnings (all are similar):

> [WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
> Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom

My maven version:

```
mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.8.1 (05c21c65bdfed0f71a2f2ada8b84da59348c4c5d)
Maven home: C:\Repo\Build\apache-maven-3.8.1\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_341, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_341\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Why is maven not being able download the plugins?
How can I upload a file?

Comment: which Maven version?, Can you show output of `mvn -e deploy:....`

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Repo\XX\YYYY\ZZ). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski I am on Apache Maven 3.8.1